# What's the difference between "gcc -lname" and "gcc libname.so ..."

Tags: gcc, linker, dynamic-linking

It seems to me that both work, any difference?

Does `gcc libname.so ...` statically links `libname.so` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -l` looks for both static and dynamic libraries (unless `-static` is given) in its library search path. `gcc ... libname.so` links dynamically with `libname.so` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc ... libname.so` is  the same as `gcc -shared -L. -lname`

Answer (score 0):

You can't *statically* link a dynamic library.  You're just playing with two different ways to give the name of the library to the compiler driver program (gcc).  larsmans is right that the -l option will look for both shared and then static libraries (unless you specify -static on the gcc call.)